# How to deconve a None shape tf.placeholder?

Tags: tensorflow

Here is the problem.:

I want to deconve a Tensor with uncertain shape(depend on the input). So I use

```
  tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32,shape=None)
```

as the tensor and  to deconv.

```
tf.nn.conv2d_transpose()
```

But tf.nn.conv2d_transpose() requires a certain parameter output_shape. And because the tf.placeholder has a shape None.....Tensorflow just cannot build the Graph.

I really don't know how to make it work, already trying everything came to me all day...Please help (T.T)

Comment: How are you expecting the transpose convolution to work without explicitly defining an output shape?

Comment: Because the output shape depends on the input...And I think I figured out a solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think i figured out a solution. I have used tensor.get_shape().as_list() to get the input shape and caculate the deconvolution output shape. But it seems tensor.get_shape() is a static method to get shape and cannot handle a tf.placeholder or tensors derived from a tf.placeholder and then cannot build the Graph. So I tried the dynamic method tf.shape() and it works!!

But I can only use sess.run(tf.shape(), feed_dict={}) to get a numpy array. If not it returns a tf.Tensor and I cannot figure out the explicit shape as int from that. Any idea on get the exact shape(with type int or numpy array) without process sess.run() before really run the whole network?